# Django REST API create a combination of URLs

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, url-routing

I have the following tables:
-Parent
-Child

With my API I have the following URLS.py

```
url(r'^parent/$', views.parent.as_view(), name='parent-list'),
url(r'^parent/(?P<pk>[\d]+)/$', views.parentDetail.as_view(), name='parent-instance'),
```

and the same for child.

however, I would like to make an instance where my URL is:

```
/parent/?P<pk>[\d]+)/$'/child/?P<pk>[\d]+)/$'
```

or even more simply

```
parent_id/child_id
```

where this prints the specific child relative to the parent. How do I go about this using DRF (Django Rest Framework)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url(r'^parent/(?P[0-9]+)/child/(?P[0-9]+)/$',  views.childDetail.as_view(), name='child-instance')

Comment: but how do children filter in relation to parents? I need more than just routing. Thanks

Comment: def get(self, request, parent_pk, pk, format=None):